# How to reset animation in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation

Here is my code:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    cloud.center.x  -= view.bounds.width
    cloud1.center.x -= view.bounds.width
    cloud2.center.x -= view.bounds.width
    cloud3.center.x -= view.bounds.width
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 12) {
        self.cloud.center.x += self.view.bounds.width*2

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 12, delay: 9, options: [],
                       animations: {
                            self.cloud1.center.x += self.view.bounds.width*2
                        },
                       completion: nil
        )
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 12, delay: 18, options: [],
                       animations: {
                            self.cloud2.center.x += self.view.bounds.width*2
                        },
                       completion: nil
        )
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 12, delay: 22, options: [],
                       animations: {
                            self.cloud3.center.x += self.view.bounds.width*2
                        },
                       completion: nil
        )
    }
}
```

I have got a redo which resets everything in the page apart from my animation which just stays in one position. How can I reset the animation in order for it to re-play the animation again?

Answer (score 0):

Your animation code moves your 4 cloud views to the right by `self.view.bounds.width*2`, by adding that amount to their center positions.

To undo that change, simply subtract the same amount.

Comment: I dont want to undo it, i want the animation to do the same thing when i press the button

Comment: Do the same thing? Animate backwards? If you want to do the same thing again forwards, you have to first put the views back in their original positions. You need to state your goal clearly.